# How to use for/in with tuples?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to do something like:

```
for (a,b) in (1,2) (2,1)
do
run_program.py $a $b
done
```

I only know the `for do done` syntax in Linux. I want to run the program with the specific two (a,b) instances (or course, it easily generalizes to much larger than two).

Comment: acronym GNU isn't understandable in this context for me (maybe others too). Tag has nothing to subject too

Comment: I am actually just talking about basic terminal syntax, I know we could do for a in 1 2
do
run_program.py $a
done   but is it possible to do for (a,b) in (1,2) (2,1)
do
run_program.py $a $b
done

Comment: Terminals have no syntax. You're talking about a shell (probably bash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no tuple construct in bash, and also no destructuring (the behavior which you're relying on to assign `a=1` and `b=2` when iterating over `(1,2)`). What you *can* do is have multiple arrays, where the same index in each refers to corresponding data, and iterate by index.

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - IMPORTANT: /bin/sh does not support arrays, you *must* use bash

a1=( 1 2 )                  # a1[0]=1; a1[1]=2
a2=( 2 1 )                  # a2[0]=2; a2[1]=1
for idx in "${!a1[@]}"; do  # iterate over indices: idx=0, then idx=1
  a=${a1[$idx]}             # lookup idx in array a1
  b=${a2[$idx]}             # lookup idx in array a2
  run_program.py "$a" "$b"  # ...and use both
done
```

Syntax pointers:

- `"${!array[@]}"` expands to the list of indices for the array `array`.
- `a1=( 1 2 )` assigns to an array named `a1`. See [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) for an introduction to arrays in bash.

---

If you have constraints in your input that allows items to be split unambiguously, it's also possible to (hackishly) use that. For an example using a pattern of behaviors explained in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
inputs='1:2,2:1,'
while IFS=: read -r -d, a b <&3; do
  run_program.py "$a" "$b" 3<&-
done 3<<<"$inputs"
```

Note that the use of `3` here is arbitrary: File descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are reserved for stdin, stdout and stderr; 3-9 are explicitly available for shell scripts to use; and in practice, higher FD numbers tend to also be available as well (but are prone to be dynamically auto-allocated to store backups or for other shell behavior; that said, a well-behaved shell won't stomp on a FD that a user has explicitly allocated, and will move an FD auto-allocated to store backups of temporarily-redirected descriptors out-of-the-way if the user puts it to explicit use).

Comment: If the values don't contain whitespace/special characters, you could also iterate over strings, right? As in: `for ab in '1 2' '2 1'; do stuff $ab; done`.

Comment: @melpomene, ...one can do much better than relying on string-splitting. See recent edits.

Comment: When using this construct, does `run_program.py` inherit file descriptor 3?

Comment: @melpomene, ...to be clear, "if the values don't contain whitespace/special characters" is a dangerous assumption to make: Just because you know what your input is *today* doesn't mean you know what your input *will ever be*, especially if producers are buggy. If you use practices that are going to fail relatively gracefully in the presence of bugs elsewhere in your tooling, then you don't end up with cascading failures (when something that's supposed to constrain your filenames fails, for instance).

Comment: @melpomene, yes, the child does inherit FD 3. I've updated to prevent that via `3<&-`, though it's not generally a concern -- being, as it is, a standard of behavior that programs should only interact with the outside world via FDs 0, 1 and 2 or new descriptors they opened themselves unless explicitly given a contrary argument.